# Thunderbird view all feeds in a folder

Tags: thunderbird, rss, feed

Is there any way to view all feeds in a folder in thunderbird? As opposed to going through the feeds one by one, have them all merged together?

As of now, clicking on a root-level folder I cannot see anything
[image]
and I have to click on an individual feed to see it.
[image]

Does the possibility exist that they can be merged, that is, I can click on CS/Software and see all of the feeds underneath it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Bamboo Feed Reader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/bamboo-feed-reader/?src=search)
It's an extension to Thunderbird that adds `merged feed reading` to Thunderbird among other features.
[image: Bamboo Feed Reader]

Comment: "This extension has NOT been rewritten with the new WebExtensions API (Firefox Quantum). No future version is planned [...]"

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Create a virtual folder/saved search.  Right click a folder-> Search Messages.  In the dialog, check search subfolders.  Select an always true criteria like Age In Day, is greater than, 0.  Save as search folder.
2. A folder in a feed account may contain 0, 1, or many feed subscriptions.  You can move subscription URLs all to one folder, using rt click->Subscribe.  Drag and drop them in that dialog.  All subsequent refreshes will go into the new folder.  (Folders themselves must be moved etc in the folderpane itself, and existing messages in previous folders must be selected/moved separately.)

Comment: I used the first method and it is exactly what I wanted. No additional software needed, still keeping separated feeds as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on `blogs and new feeds`,choose subscribe. Now drag each item to the top level. After moving click close. An empty folder will be created for each item,that you can remove by deleting that folder,by pressing `delete` key. Hope it will work.

Second way around is to export item via a opml file and import to [feedly](http://feedly.com), then organize the items to top level. Then export the items as a opml file and import it again on Thunderbird.